# What happens to LOST String objects

Tags: java, garbage-collection

```
Line 1: String x = "Java";
Line 2: x.concat(" Rules!");
Line 3: System.out.println("x = " + x);
```

Output is "x= Java"

Line 1:creates a new String object, gives the value "Java", and refer  x to it.

Line 2: VM creates a 2nd String object with value "Java Rules!" but nothing refers to it. THE 2nd STRING OBJECT IS INSTANTLY LOST; YOU CANNOT GET TO IT.

As these String Objects are created in Heap, will the 2nd object be Garbage Collected.

Comment: Note that `"x = "+x` creates a third String.

Answer (score 7):

Enosh, in java Strings are immutable, so you should assign

```
x = x.concat(" Rules");
```

for the second line and then it will work.

The second object will be GC'd eventually because there is no longer an entity refering to it.

Comment: The question was not about making something work - Enosh wanted to know what happens to the result String of the concat operation - whether it's created and stored somewhere or not.

Comment: Yes I know, but I'd rather fix the error, so that people who look at this question, don't get mistaken.

Answer (score 5):

Absolutely.  That's the whole point of garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with all the others that it get garbage collected. But I guetss that the compiler can remove this at all during compilation as the concat methods does only affect method local fields and therefor the whole statement doesn't make sense.